# runtime error (SIGSEGV) in SPOJ

Tags: c++

I was solving this simple [problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/) based on prime number generation. In Xcode it ran successfully. But when I submitted the solution to [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/) it says that `runtime error SIGSEGV`. I searched in the internet about what is this runtime error and when I checked my solution I didn't see any problem. **So if there is any problem in my code what is it and how can it be solved?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main() {
   int tcases = 0;
   cin >> tcases;
   const int ccase = tcases;
   tcases = 0;

   while (tcases != ccase) {
     int m = 0, n = 0;
     cin >> m >> n;
     std::list<int> p;
     int i = 0;
     if (m == 1) i = ++m;
     if (m > 1) i = m;
     for (; i <= n; p.push_back(i), ++i);
     // get all the elements
     for (auto first = p.begin(), last = p.end(); first != last; ++first) {
         if (*first == 2) continue;
         else if (*first == 3) continue;
         else if (*first == 5) continue;
         else if (*first == 7) continue;
         else if (*first % 2 == 0) p.erase(first);
         else if (*first % 3 == 0) p.erase(first);
         else if (*first % 5 == 0) p.erase(first);
         else if (*first % 7 == 0) p.erase(first);
     }
     for (auto &elem: p)
         cout << elem << endl;

     cout << endl;
     ++tcases;
    } 
   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you say,

```
p.erase(first);
```

Erase removes the current element and returns a iterator to the next element in the list, which you are not storing anywhere in your code. And you are incrementing `first`in your for loop, so when the next time loop will run, `first is not pointing to a valid location and hence the runtime error.`

Change your `for loop` to following

```
for (auto first = p.begin(), last = p.end(); first != last;) {
            if (*first == 2)
            {

                first++;
                continue;
            }
            else if (*first == 3)
            {

                first++;
                continue;
            }
            else if (*first == 5) 
            {

                first++;
                continue;
            }
            else if (*first == 7) 
            {
                first++;
                continue;
            }
            else if (*first % 2 == 0) 
                first = p.erase(first);
            else if (*first % 3 == 0) 
            first = p.erase(first);
            else if (*first % 5 == 0) 
            first = p.erase(first);
            else if (*first % 7 == 0)
                first = p.erase(first);
            else
                first++;
        }
```

P.S. : Sharing the code just to show how to use erase.

Comment: works for me though,tested with different inputs, see if you changed it properly. however your issue was you were using     erase in a wrong way.

Comment: On my system it works as it should. But when I submit it shows wrong answer.

Comment: wrong answer or runtime error?
if the answer is wrong you need to check your logic.

Comment: I changed the **for** loop part as you said. When I run on my system the results are displayed properly. But when I submit my code it says `wrong answer`.

Comment: I tried to remove the error, and i guess it worked for you since you are not getting the runtime error now.
For the logic part you need to check yourself :)